# Java delay method run

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks, task

I need to run some code after a period of time without blocking the current method.

I tried the following 2 approaches:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Start");

    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            System.out.println("done");
            this.cancel();

        }
    }, 4000L);

    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("done");
        }
    }, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    executor.shutdown();

    System.out.println("Stop");
}
```

The problem is that the first does block the app and the second does not allow main to exit until it finishes;

How to run the code after some time and exit the current method right after scheduling it ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? The second approach _will_ run  asynchronously, i.e. does not block your methods!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a own thread and set it as Daemon:

```
        final Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20000);
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("20 seconds over");

        }
    });
    myThread.setDaemon(true);
    myThread.start();
```

An alternative is to create the Executor with a ThreadFactory, in which you set the created Thread as Daemon. You have to use these function:

```
Excecutors.newScheduledThreadPool(int corePoolSize, ThreadFactory threadFactory)
```

Comment: making it a daemon thread will make the app exit right after calling the code; --> If the thread needs to run something in 10 seconds, it not not exist anymore at that point.

Comment: I thought that was your wish ('and the second does not allow main to exit until it finishes;'). In my example i do nothing after myThread.start(). In a real world app there could be done anything in the mainThread (or in other non Daemon threads). You could leave out the setDAemon(true). Than the app will exit after System.out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the job you create to outlive the java process that created it, then you will have to launch another process.  [Commons exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) can help with that, since launching a process from java is not as simple as it may first appear.

If you set the thread as daemon then your process exits, then the daemon thread will also be killed - its address space is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [ScheduledExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use a scheduled executor:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

It has a schedule method, a schedule at fixed rate method and a schedule with fixed delay method.